# Eigenvalues/vectors of the Laplace transform?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplace-transform

I'm learning about eigenvalues and eigenvectors (finally starting to get them). This might be a silly question, but what is/are the eigenvector(s) of the Laplace transform? I mean, what $\vec{x}_{i}$'s and $\lambda_{i}$'s satisfy
\begin{align}\mathcal{L}\left\{\vec{x}_{i}\right\}&=\lambda_{i}\vec{x}_{i}.\end{align}
I'm just trying to extrapolate a bit from the fact that
\begin{align}D_{t}e^{\lambda t}&=\lambda e^{\lambda t},\end{align}
but I cannot think of any function that remains unchanged under the transformation.

Comment: Eigenvalues only make sense for operators that act on a single space. The Laplace transform goes from t space to s space, so eigenvalues won't have any real meaning. The same is true for a linear map between two different finite dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Laplace transform of $t^p$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{s^{p+1}}$ for $p>-1$. Take $p=-1/2$.

Comment: You mean $-\frac12$, right?

Comment: Is this the only one?

Comment: SBareS - thanks. @jm324354 - dunno, this is the only one I know off the top of my head.